# What will be the SQL Statements for inserting values to a table which has two foreign key and the two tables are are independent

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have two tables `table1` and `table2` with some data and the `id` of table 1 and table 2 both are the foreign keys in `table3`.

How can I write a SQL statement to insert the data from `table1` and `table2` into `table3`?

I have data in `table1` and `table2` but no data in `table3` - I have to populate that using the other two.

Comment: I have tried to set a relation like tried joining two tables with the with the one but there is no data in the table3 so it hasn't worked

Comment: what do you mean when you say you have to populate table3? you want to blindy insert all combination of table1 and 2?

Answer (score 0):

Use an `Update` with `joins` 
Something like this...

```
UPDATE t3
SET x=A, y=B, z=C
FROM TABLE3 t3
inner join table1 t1
on t3.tbl1id=t1.id 
inner join table2 t2
on t3.tbl2id=t2.id
```

Comment: I want to update only the Ids of table 1 and table 2 in table3 nothing else than that only ids

Comment: the x,y and z in the above query could be any column in table3, including ids of table1 and table2. But realize this, once you do that you might break the mapping chain between Table3 and table1/ table2, since you are using those columns to join with those tables.

Comment: BUt i have no data in the table3 how it will compare and update in table 3

Comment: I see. Can you correlate table1 and table2? if yes, then you can write an insert query based on that for table3.